# ValueError: Input 0 of layer MyModel is incompatible with the layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have the following lines:

```
print(train_features[27].shape)
preds = model.predict(train_features[27])
```

And I am facing the following error:

```
(30, 128, 128, 3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-8caa4ecfc24d> in <module>()
      1 print(train_features[27].shape)
----> 2 preds = model.predict(train_features[27])

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1145           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1146             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1148             else:
   1149               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1801, in predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1790, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1783, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1751, in predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 264, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" is '

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "MyModel" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 30, 128, 128, 3), found shape=(None, 128, 128, 3)
```

The print function shows that the input value for layer 0 is (30 , 128 , 128 , 3) , yet it gives me the error.

Comment: Change the third line to: `features = train_features[27]` `preds = model.predict(features.reshape([1, *features.shape]))`

Comment: Just so you know in future, it works because the model expects to receive an array containing a batch of multiple inputs, not just 1 input. So adding an extra dimension makes it work because it is effectively now a batch with just 1 input contained within it.

Comment: OK thanks you, Do you have any resources to learn more about it?